# dbo.M7_* objects (stored procs) in my production database. What product are these from?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have inherited a database from a predecessor who is long gone... There are about a hundred stored procs in the database that all start with dbo.M7_   They appear to be something to do with source control of some sort, but I have no idea what product they are associated with.  I don't see any connection between them and any other table/proc.  I would like to remove them from my system but I need to understand why they were there first.  No one who is still here remembers what they do, they just remember them showing up in the database one day.

Does anyone know what they are?

Comment: Any clues in the stored procedure definitions?

Comment: Does it cause any problems ? Better is to run a server side sql trace (week or month - u have to decide based on your business cycle) to check if they are being called by any application or not.